# Process get errors

Tags: java, input, process

I need help with Java Process. I want to separate normal input from errors. I have a webview console, and I want to display normal input in white, and errors in red.

I have catch every input already

```
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(getProcess().getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                        String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
server.writeToConsole(server.getConsole().getLineColorFromLogLevel(line), line);

                        }
                        reader.close();
```

How can I catch the errors?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english!

**EDIT:**
I want to detect stacktraces what I get from the process

up

Answer (score 0):

You can place the line reading logic within a try block and print once read is successful. And write logic to print error in catch block.

Comment: You can read from anywhere but to you will have to differentiate between normal read and error. If you are reading from a process and if there is some kind of flag exists indicating normal and error line then  your job is just to treat them differently.

Comment: How can I distinguish them?

Comment: You can use errorreader to read the errors which will give you all the errors.

Comment: Error reader? How can I use it? Can you give me a link or something?

Comment: I want to detect stacktraces what I get from the process

Comment: Check this out. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/process_geterrorstream.htm

Comment: The stacktraces not in the errorstream. They are inside the normal input stream.